# How to flash Nexus S (currently on custom AOSP build) with stock Gingerbread by Google (Android 2.3.3)

Tags: samsung-nexus-s, stock-android, vanilla-android

I have a Nexus S which I have flashed with a custom Android build. Now I need access to the Android Market and some other Google services and therefore I need the stock Android from Google.

How can I revert my phone back to Google's build of Gingerbread (Android 2.3.3 which includes Google apps)

Comment: What custom build do you have?  Do you have a custom recovery?

Comment: I did not know you could not access the market with Nexus S custom ROM! I'm on a custom ROM permrooted HTC DHD and have no issue whatsoever... what's the error you are getting?

Comment: @Matthew-Read I built the android source and flashed to the phone. So self-made custom.

Comment: @Stefano I built it myself. When Android is built from source, no Google applications or services are present.

Comment: interesting!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a full stock ROM for the Nexus S (via [XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=955719)): http://android.clients.google.com/packages/ota/google_crespo/f182cf141e6a.signed-soju-ota-102588.f182cf14.zip (MD5: `3e8908941043951da5a34bb2043dd1a0`)

You *should* be able to name that update.zip and put it in the root of your SD card; upon reboot it will be installed.

Comment: I do not need root. There don't seem to be any stock images provided by Google, and fastboot does not seem to work with image dumps which have been made using other custom backup tools like nandroid. Rebooting into recovery and using (update.zip) also always fails with signature verification. I guess I'll have to use one of the custom tools for recovery.

Comment: I guess that works for the Nexus One. Didn't work for the Nexus S though.

Comment: Shoot, didn't see that was for the N1.  Didn't expect Google to name the firmware the same, sorry about that.  Updated answer.

Comment: Bingo! I've googled the whole day and couldn't find this. Thanks mate. Also Google just released [hardware drivers](http://code.google.com/android/nexus/drivers.html) for those using AOSP, I'm including them here for reference.